# Is there a way to convert syntax highlighting file from TextPad to gedit?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gedit, textpad

Is there any script available which automatically translates a .syn file used by TextPad into a .lang file used by GtkSourceView in gedit? Or at least, any recursive pattern which may be easily substituted?

thanks for your help